# Could File::Find::Rule be patched to automatically handle filename character encoding/decoding?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

Suppose I have a file with name `æ` (UNICODE : 0xE6, UTF8 : 0xC3 0xA6) in the current directory.

Then, I would like to use [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) to locate it:

```
use feature qw(say);
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule;

my $fn = 'æ';
my @files = File::Find::Rule->new->name($fn)->in('.');
say $_ for @files;
```

The output is empty, so apparently this did not work.

If I try to encode the filename first:

```
use Encode;

my $fn = 'æ';
my $fn_utf8 = Encode::encode('UTF-8', $fn, Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
my @files = File::Find::Rule->new->name($fn_utf8)->in('.');
say $_ for @files;
```

The output is:

```
Ã¦
```

So it found the file, but the returned filename is not decoded into a Perl string. To fix this, I can decode the result, replacing the last line with:

```
say Encode::decode('UTF-8', $_, Encode::FB_CROAK) for @files;
```

The question is if both the encoding and decoding could/should have been done automatically by `File::Find::Rule` so I could have used my original program and not have had to worry about encoding and decoding at all?

(For example, could `File::Find::Rule` have used [`I18N::Langinfo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/I18N::Langinfo) to determine that the current locale's codeset is `UTF-8` ?? )

Comment: F::F::R simply use `readdir`. That's the one that would need to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I wish. If there's was a major Perl project I'd work on, this would be it.

The issue is that there could be badly-encoded file names, including file names encoded using a different encoding than expected. That means the first thing needed is a way of round-tripping badly-encoded file names through a decode-encode process. I think Python uses the surrogate pair code points to represent the bad bytes.

You would need a pragma to ensure backwards compatibility.

Comment: Seems like [`utf8::all`](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8::all) has a patch for `readdir`..

Comment: More info here:  https://github.com/doherty/utf8-all/issues/11 .. See also discussion at perl5.porters http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2013/08/msg206341.html

Comment: utf8::all assumes a UTF-8 system. Not all unix systems are UTF-8, and no Windows system is. It also doesn't address the problem I mentioned. You're not guaranteed to be able to access all the file names returned as they may not be accurate.